# Is there any way to make TexMaker work like the MathJax editor on Math Exchange?

Tags: texmaker

I am super new to the Tex world and I would like to start being organized with my math sheets.

I posted a few questions on the Math Exchange and I really like the synchronizing between the source code and the viewer because I can easily know when I make a syntax mistake or when I write something wrong.

Is there any way to reproduce the feature in TexMaker? I've added `-synctex=1` but it doesn't seem to work. `:c`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Since your question is about TeXMaker, why not to use the [tag:texmaker] tag?

Comment: @José Carlos Santos Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: MathJax cannot interpret all LaTeX input, but only a subset thereof and, in some cases, it even has different syntax.

Comment: @egreg So there's no way of making it work with sync?

Comment: @Neox SyncTeX is a completely different thing: it allows synchronization between source and PDF output.

Comment: The problem is to know what kind of dynamic outputs you need. Advanced features can't be dynamic because of the huge LaTeX ecosystem.

Comment: @egreg Then, SyncTex effectively acts when I press F7 and a red rectangle frames the corresponding output part of the selection in the source code? Btw, I started solving some math tests using LaTeX and I think it's a great idea. I can write faster on a worksheet since I don't have to worry about calligraphy (I'm obsessed with having the final product of a test/theorem/formula etc beautifully written) and then I can copy-paste to LaTeX the important parts and insist on the explanations rather than algebraic manipulation and numerical calculation which are trivial.

Comment: @projetmbc Basically what I wished to achieve was code compiling while I write so I can be more efficient in detecting typos, exactly like in the Math Exchange editor.

Comment: Maybe something like [this VSCode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=James-Yu.latex-workshop) could be your Graal. See [this feature](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Compile#auto-build-latex).

Comment: @projetmbc Gave a look on it and seems pretty professional. Gonna make a post on the math forum and then I'll install it. Thanks for the advice!